# groovy quoted function identifiers

Tags: groovy

Groovy allows a quoted function identifier such as

```
def "my cool method"()
{
    "foo"
}
```

but I can't find this in the specification. Is it a groovy feature or maybe some lib relies on quotes being used in identifiers? Or is it an omission in the official doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an integral part of Groovy to be able to do this. If it is missing in the documentation, then it is a documentation bug at most. Basically the same as written at http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_quoted_identifiers is also valid for function names.